# Solutions to systems of quadratic multivariate polynomials with diagonal quadratic forms

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, systems-of-equations

I am looking for an analytical solution to a system of quadratic equations of the form:

$$
    \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{A}_i \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{b}_i^T\mathbf{x} + c_i=0 ~~~~~~~~ i = 1,..,n
$$

where $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $c_i \in \mathbb{R}$, and $\mathbf{A}_i \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ are diagonal matrices.

If it helps, I can simplify $\mathbf{b}_i^T\mathbf{x}$ to $d_ix_i,  d_i \in \mathbb{R}$.